# How do I restart Cinnamon from the tty?

Tags: tty, cinnamon

I installed Cinnamon on my Ubuntu 12.04, and it works well, but sometimes it just freezes for no reason. I can move my mouse but can't click on anything.

So I want to restart Cinnamon from tty, like I used to do with gnome shell. How do I do that?

I tried `killall cinnamon` and nothing happened.

Then I tried `export DISPLAY=:0.0` , `cinnamon --replace` and still nothing.

I guess the command `cinnamon` is not valid.
I don't want to restart the whole X server because then all of my windows will get closed. I just want to restart the window manager cause I believe it is causing the problem.

Answer (score 154):

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type r and hit enter.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Worked for me (Deb.7)

Comment: In my case, Cinnamon is completely frozen and doesn't respond to Alt+F2.

Comment: this is simply wrong since the question is "[...]  from the **tty**?"

Comment: I completely agree with @Lucas here, but I'll hold off on voting it down just because it's a very useful shortcut to know, even if not from the tty as the OP describes.  It might conceivably work while cinnamon is not properly functional though?

Comment: I agree too, but I was looking for "debian restart cinnamon" and google showed me this solution and it works for me. So +1

Comment: linux is amazin.

Comment: Does not work in Mint 17 Cinnamon. Just an error that the "r" command is not found.

Comment: @kmarsh An update should solve that. Works on Mint 18 Cinnamon – and saves me from installing an extra applet just for that rarely used functionality. As some applets require a Cinnamon restart after being installed, it's indeed a very useful shortcut – though I fully agree it's not the answer the OP was after. First hit on a Google search for "restart Cinnamon", so +1 and let it stay :)

Comment: @Izzy: Indeed, t works now. +1.

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Escape, and don't forget to vote for this man's answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1006795/400409

Comment: Alt + F2 might also work, even if its not shown up (happens when some processes are frozen). Just hitting Alt + F2 then "r" then ENTER often does the job, even if there is no visual feedback.

Answer (score 82):

The `cinnamon --replace` process can be sent the HUP signal which will trigger it to restart, thus preserving your open window and running applications.

```
$ pkill -HUP -f "cinnamon --replace"
```

This will take care to send the HUP signal to a process that matches the pattern, "cinnamon --replace". The signal HUP (SIGHUP) tells the process to "Hang Up".

Comment: This is first solution that's worked for me with no nasty side effects. For those who don't know.. if you can't start the terminal, press `Alt+F2` to get to a TTY, login with an admin-capable account, become root, and then enter that command. You might have to `Alt+F[n]` to get back to your X TTY.

Comment: What is the `cinnamon --replace` process doing?

Comment: @Seanny123 - restarts cinnamon but replaces the current  one with a new one.

Comment: ah, so the process go stuck trying to replace the existing cinnamon instance, which was causing the freeze, which is why I needed to kill it?

Comment: @Seanny123 - cinnamon is hung up, the replace triggers a restart but leaves all the subsequent "child" bits alone.

Comment: AFAIK it is `Ctrl+Alt+F[n]` usually to switch tty-s. Also patience might help - today I got my keyboard back after about 2 hours of frozen interface.

Answer (score 64):

This happens to me a lot, too, and this thread is one of the top results when googling for "restart cinnamon". Unfortunately, the instructions don't work for me (only because the display number is wrong!). For future visitors, here's what I do that always helps me.

1. Cinnamon freezes
2. Switch tty. I usually go to tty6, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>
3. If you need to login first, do so.
4. Type `w` (yes, just the letter) and press enter. This commands does a lot of different things, but you need it to figure out the number of the display you are using. The display number is in the column `FROM`. Mine is `:0` (yes, including the colon).
5. Assuming that cinnamon is already dead (which you would notice by the windows lacking titles and that you can't move different windows around, and perhaps even not being able to use the keyboard), you type `export DISPLAY=:0; cinnamon &`, and don't forget the colon. I add the ampersand (&) only not to keep that tty busy.

This always works for me, and I don't lose open windows.
Also, I keep these instructions in a file called restartcinnamon, which is just a text file. I keep the file in my Dropbox folder, so no matter what machine I am on I can just type `cat ~/Dropbox/restartcinnamon` if I need to be reminded of how to do it.

Comment: After doing this, my 3 screens (3 monitors) become like one. Any advice?

Comment: The fix then is to open up the displays panel and then click OK. Any way around this? Multi-monitor support has always been flakey on Linux.

Comment: Also worth noting: the TTY doesn't take the current Num-lock state.  Had some confusing time figuring out why my password was incorrect...

Comment: The above worked (thanks!). I use 2 monitors, I disable my laptop and use the main monitor with "disper -S", after the cinnamon restart I had a black screen. I used "disper -s" (note lowercase s here, meaning primary screen) to switch back to the laptop display and...the main monitor came on instead. If anyone is using disper, maybe try the big-S and little-s variants? I use Synapse so I just typed Ctrl-Shift-Space (my hotkey) and then "disper -S"

Answer (score 50):

Cinnamon has a direct keyboard-shortcut to restart the desktop without restarting any of the running applications:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd>

Which will probably still work in some cases when the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> Method does not work anymory

Comment: Yes, this is what I want!

Comment: Thank you for this. My Cinnamon was on fallback mode and `Alt+F2` doesn't do the same thing, but `Ctrl+Alt+Esc` worked.

Comment: This is the best answer in 2022 on Linux Mint 20.3

Answer (score 25):

The easiest sulution would be:

```
killall -HUP cinnamon
```

Comment: Worked for me perfectly.

Comment: This logged me out from the existing Cinnamon session, though.

Comment: Cinnamon sometimes freezes on my system. When I try this (in console mode, Ctrl+Alt+F1, works even with frozen Cinnamon) and then return back to normal (Ctrl+Alt+F7), Cinnamon shows an error message saying that it crashed. I can then click "yes" to restart it (if I click "no", I failed and need to restart) and everything works like normal again. Only windows that were inverted with the "press Win+I to invert windows" extension are no longer inverted. Tested with Cinnamon 3.2.7 on Debian 9.11.

Answer (score 15):

You can restart Cinnamon by:

1. pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>,
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (restart Xorg),
3. in **TTY** use command: `sudo service mdm restart`

Comment: Best answer here, needs more upvotes.

Comment: `mdm restart` will close all open sessions and open windows.

Comment: Latest versions of Linux Mint use lightdm as the DM. So, in this case you can use `sudo service lightdm restart` instead of `mdm restart`

Answer (score 7):

When you kill cinnamon, check if it hasn't stopped writing `killall cinna` and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If the rest of the word appears, make it die with `killall -9 cinnamon`, and then restart it, using what you tried but without `--replace`:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0; cinnamon
```

Answer (score 3):

The following combination of the above comments worked for me:

1. Ctrl-Alt F1   to switch to terminal 1.   Log in if necessary
2. `w`  (yes, single letter "w" is a command) to see your display # in the FROM column).  For me it was `:0`  (includes the colon).  Also,  the TTY column will have the terminal # of your cinnamon session (for me it was `tty8`).
3. `cinnamon --replace --clutter-display=:0 2> /dev/null &`

   Notes on this last command:

   - `:0` was my display #.
   - `&` returns control of the terminal
   - the `--clutter-display`, if not entered, uses the DISPLAY, variable, which is why some of the prior suggestions did EXPORT first.   But you can just pass the argument directly to cinnamon.  See `cinnamon --help` for more.
   - `2> /dev/null` redirects stderr to nowhere so my terminal does not get cluttered with messages.
4. Ctrl+Alt+F8 to return to my window cinnamon environment (F8 for me since my terminal was tty8 per the `w` command above. For you it may not be F8.)

Net result:  this restarted cinnamon in my terminal (tty8) without losing my windows.

Answer (score 1):

try this

1. pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
2. `export DISPLAY=:0.0; cinnamon --replace`

Comment: -1 The question says very clearly that this didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the `w -ous` command and check if there is number for `DISPLAY`. If there isn't a number just use `startx` and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to GUI.

Answer (score 1):

After you have switched to tty Try this `killall -HUP cinnamon`. 
Press Ctrl + Alt + F7.
Cinnamon will ask you if you want to restart cinnamon.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem periodicaly due to gfx driver for HP Envy.

I need to do one or both of the following depending on the circumstancel;

1. As the top answer, and others, suggest - restart cinnamon - Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, press <kbd>R</kbd>, and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. *(Do this if the taskbar becomes unresponsive, or windows do not actually have focus, on-click etc. eg, you may be clicking or typing in the window that seems to have focus, but the one behind is receiving the event - this can even he hidden completely behind the window you THINK is active)*
2. Switch to a virtual console, then back to X - Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, to go to the console, then press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to return back to X. - *(Do this if the WHOLE screen is unresponsive - at least you don't SEE anything happening - this fixes things for me at least.)*

This problem exists for me still - Linux Mint 17.x - hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes have that problem when locking the screen: the lock screen doesn't appear and my system seems frozen, with no input working, and I can't log back in.

My solution is to kill the cinnamon-screensaver process.

```
% pkill cinnamon-screen
```

pkill uses the info in /proc/PID/stat, and Linux only stores the first 15 characters of the command name, so using "pkill cinnamon-screensaver" won't work.

Now my system is unlocked, input works again and I have not lost any of my windows.  To make the system lockable again, I restart the screensaver.

```
% nohup cinnamon-screensaver > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I redirect to /dev/null to avoid the creation of the nohup.out file.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! All the expert answers above failed miserably. This solution works on my high configuration system installed with AMD Ryzen Threadripper CPU and Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try to "soft-restart" cinnamon by `sudo kill -USR1 <PID of your cinnamon process>`. @Daniel's answer is correct but will kill X server while `SIGUSR1` won't, at least on my machine... It turns out, as well, that all the windows preserve content and remain usable after that. Wondering if this is true for the others.

Answer (score 0):

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (Kill x server),

That seemed to work for me. 
(*However I had started a second cinnamon session (`cinnamon &`) doing so caused only the wallpapaer to be shown. I then did the Kill x server keystroke. That appeared to restarted the remaining cinnamon shell, and killed it again, I think thats how I got back to normal. It did the login zoom to desktop thing, so I was satisfied at that point; (LM 17.1 Rebecca)*)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all previous solutions, but none of them works.
The solution that works for me is 

`killall cinnamon-session`

Hope this helps. 
P/s: My linuxmint version is cinnamon 18.3

Answer (score 0):

Once I had an unusual problem, just after a laptop was in standby. There was nothing but a black screen, but the mouse was working. In TTY2 I tried the following command several times:

```
pkill -HUP -f "cinnamon --replace"
```

but nothing happened.

Then in tty2, I killed the cinnamon screensaver and it worked:

```
killall cinnamon-screensaver
```

Then the black screen disappeared and then by restarting the cinnamon everything became okay.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes do experiments with my cinnamon desktop and this problem happens a lot. I solve this problem by logging in to a tty terminal and issuing the command `sudo systemctl restart gdm.service`.

Answer (score 0):

`STRG + ALT + ESC` helps me to restart Cinnamon 4.8.6 under Linux Mint 20.1 to restart the Cinnamon Session

Answer (score 0):

What worked best for me is to invoke the call from the [Cinnamon source code](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon/blob/master/src/cinnamon-global.c#L1130).
Works on 5.4.10. Also does not prompt for fallback mode.

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.Cinnamon /org/Cinnamon org.Cinnamon.Eval string:"global.real_restart()"
```