# Cinnamon: Restart x-cursor-theme without reboot the system

Tags: themes, cinnamon

I have changed my cursor theme system-wide in this way:

/etc/rc.local:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
rm -f /tmp/HOME
while [[ ! -f /tmp/HOME ]]
do
    sleep 1
done
HOME=$(< /tmp/HOME)
if [[ -f $HOME/.icons/default/index.theme ]]; then
    ln -sf $HOME/.icons/default/index.theme /etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme
fi
# apply changes now.
exit 0
```

/etc/profile.d/write_home_dir_in_tmp_folder.sh:

```
echo ~ > /tmp/HOME
```

This way after reboot, if x-cursor-theme still pointed to the old path, once pointed to the user path, the changes are not applied and are only applied from the second reboot onwards.
It would take another line in the rc.local file that "apply changes now.".
I've searched the internet but can't find an answer.
Can someone help me?

P.S.

`pstree | grep session` returns an empty string.

`wmctrl -m` returns:

```
Name: Mutter (Muffin)
Class: N/A
PID: N/A
Window manager's "showing the desktop" mode: N/A
```

`echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` returns:

```
cinnamon
```

`echo $GDMSESSION` returns:

```
cinnamon
```

`echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` returns:

```
X-Cinnamon
```

Comment: More input is required at this point. It depends on the session which is running. You could improve your question with

`pstree | grep session`

`wmctrl -m`

`echo $DESKTOP_SESSION `

`echo $GDMSESSION`

`echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`

Comment: Ok, I have update the question.

Comment: Your Question seems to be related to this a bit outdated [Q/A](https://askubuntu.com/a/523436/545672). Maybe you can also think about gsetting but you could try first

    `$ pkill -HUP -f "cinnamon --replace"`

-- Or -- you could try something like this from [here](https://techblog.jeppson.org/2016/02/fix-inconsistent-mouse-cursors-in-linux-mint/)

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme "$CURSOR" && sudo update-alternatives --set x-cursor-theme <the path you like>/$CURSOR/cursor.theme`

Comment: if that answers the question, i can promote the comment to an answer

Comment: Restarting cinnamon doesn't restart the mouse pointer as well, so it doesn't fix the problem. Before asking this question I searched far and wide.

Comment: @MarioPalumbo AFAIK cursor theme are used by X server not by session manager or application. Probably you need to restart Xorg server  and to do so, restart the running DM (Display Manager). As in this post: https://askubuntu.com/q/1220/26246 . DM in current Desktop Environments is handling login too, so it will kill running user applications and require login again.